# Windows Emulators installation on VS 2017

Tags: windows-mobile, visual-studio-2017

I tried to install VS 2017  with the option selected for Windows Mobile development. VS 2017 installed but with an error for the installation of the Windows Mobile Emulators. The error was "pixel format invalid" ??? . 
How Can I do to solve this problem?
this is my log file:
"
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26208.0)

Incomplete components
    Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Anniversary Edition) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Phone.Emulator,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79501' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2000
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\eskan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170623143603_001_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\Users\eskan\Downloads\Compressed\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79501\WinSdkInstall.ps1""" -SetupExe sdksetup.exe -SetupLogFolder standalonesdk -PackageId Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795 -LogFile """C:\Users\eskan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170623143603_001_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log""" -SetupParameters """/features OptionId.AvrfExternal OptionId.WindowsSoftwareDevelopmentKit OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.NetFxSoftwareDevelopmentKit /quiet /norestart /OriginalSource """"""C:\Users\eskan\Downloads\Compressed\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79501\sdksetup.exe""""""""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: 2000
        Return code details: The pixel format is invalid.

Package 'Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0,version=10.0.14393.4,chip=x64' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2000
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Impacted components
        Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Anniversary Edition) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Phone.Emulator,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\eskan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170623143603_002_Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\Users\eskan\Downloads\Compressed\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0,version=10.0.14393.4,chip=x64\WinSdkInstall.ps1""" -SetupExe EmulatorSetup.exe -SetupLogFolder emulator -PackageId Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0 -LogFile """C:\Users\eskan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170623143603_002_Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0.log""" -SetupParameters """/quiet /norestart /OriginalSource """"""C:\Users\eskan\Downloads\Compressed\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Visual.Studio.Enterprise.Pro.Community.2017_p30download.com\Win10_Emulator_10.0.14393.0,version=10.0.14393.4,chip=x64\EmulatorSetup.exe""""""""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: 2000
        Return code details: The pixel format is invalid.

"

Answer (score 3):

It is a Windows system error.  From the WinError.h SDK file:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_PIXEL_FORMAT
//
// MessageText:
//
// The pixel format is invalid.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_PIXEL_FORMAT       2000L
```

It belongs to a group of error codes that are reserved for OpenGL.  That doesn't exactly get a lot of use anymore on Windows, but did make a come-back since it is the Unix equivalent of DirectX.  The emulators you are trying to install do boot Unix.

So most obvious conclusion to draw is to take it literally, your video adapter is running in an unusual mode.  That's pretty hard to do these days, most everybody's adapter runs at 32 bits per pixel and I don't think modern Windows versions (>= 8) even allow modifying it.  Win7 did.  The emulators would definitely need 32bpp to get their job done.

If that's not a match at all then "2000" is entirely too nice a round number and it could mean anything.  Long shot is to step through the [trouble-shooter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx).  I don't see a lot of programmers having this problem, you'd get close to conclude that the machine just isn't up to the job.  My money is on the video adapter setting.

Answer (score 1):

You should install without Microsoft Mobile Emulator for Windows 10 and follow below instruction.

1. Repair your System with an elevated CMD and enter `sfc /scannow` and `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`.
2. If there are errors reinstall Windows 10 - keep Settings and Apps.
3. Run `sfc /scannow` and `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` again till there is no error. Maybe search the internet for more tips running these apps.
4. Download the Emulator Installation File: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=822928
5. Choose the second option and download all setup files.
6. Start the `EmulatorSetup.exe` with Admin Rights.

There is a similar problem with the VS2015 emulator. Refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecd38931-63dd-42ac-b3f2-30768db2e50a/vs-2015-emulators-for-windows-mobile-10010240-cannot-be-installed-error-2000?forum=vssetup

Alternatively according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838863.aspx, update the graphics driver because the error code (=2000) is caused by the graphics driver. This link is helpful: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928493.